# Portable format for Analytics

Tags: python, r

I want to develop a simple function in R, that can be run on multiple platforms, and I've heard of PFA (Portable Format for Analytics), built by the Data Mining Group, which seems to be a promising avenue to achieve the same.
So, i've used the Aurelius package to convert R code to PFA, as follows:

```
 pfaDocument <- pfa.config(
    input = list(a = avro.double,
                 b = avro.double),
    output = avro.double,
    action = expression(
      c <- input$a+input$b,
      c <- input$a + c
      )
  )
json(x = pfaDocument, fileName = "something.pfa")
```

This gives me a text file in JSON format, and it seems to be exactly the way i need it to be.

However, when i try to load it as a scoring engine in Python (using package Titus) with the following code:

```
import json
from titus.genpy import PFAEngine
engine = PFAEngine.fromJson(json.load(open("C:/Users/vishnu.dutt/Documents/something.pfa")))
```

I get this error:

*SchemaParseException: Could not resolve the following types:
    {"a": "double", "b": "double"} (No "type" property: {u'a': u'double', u'b': u'double'})*

I don't have too much experience with either Python or PFA, so i'd really appreciate if someone could lend me a hand here.

P.S. - Sorry if this question's already been posted. I've been looking around a lot for some answers, but just couldn't find anything that is relatable.

Answer (score 0):

You could check some of the examples of how they have tried to load models (PFA) here: https://github.com/AlpineNow/PFA_Examples

I'm guessing it expects the model itself to be an argument. Please try a couple of examples.